# Is there a way to restore rvm installation if i have the .rvm folder backup?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I recently re-installed my operating system and before that i made a backup of my ~/.rvm folder that contains all my gems, ruby installations and configurations.
Doing all those steps from scratch is a bit difficult due to my internet being painfully sluggish.

So my question is:
Is there any way to have the same configuration as before using my backup of the ~/.rvm folder.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Installation**

Put your backup back to `~/.rvm`. Be sure, that you setup rvm correctly with:

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After a `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` (or opening a new terminal), rvm should be back.

**Test if it worked**

To test your installation, do the following:

```
type rvm | head -n 1 # should return: "rvm is a function"
```

**Note**

Ruby and some gems have binaries specifically compiled for your system. If the installed libraries have changed (or are missing), expect errors. A reinstallation of the failing gem/ruby should help.

Comment: When i open the new terminal i get **/home/javier/.rvm/scripts/color: Permission denied** at the start.

Comment: The rvm backup might still belong to your old user. Do a `ls -l ~/.rvm` to find out who is the owner and what are the access rights (scripts should be executable, all files have to be read-/writeable for your user)

Comment: To change the owner, do a `chown -R javier ~/.rvm`

Comment: It works, rvm recognize my ruby version. But when i type `$ ruby --version` i get **/home/javier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby: No such file or directory** and the file exist, y check that. A permission thing ??

Comment: I solved the latest issue installing the 64-bits version of ruby since i now have an x64 installation of the Operating System. Thanks !!